# Angular - Preview form data on image before print

Tags: html, angular, forms, web

I need help to understand how I can fill a form and at the same time have an image of the label next to the form which will show user the data which it is entering will go where in the label before it prints I have seen something like this for credit card payments, as the user is entering the CC details there is a CC image next to the form were the details are also getting populated. What is this feature called and if anyone can refer me to some tutorial or blogs.

Appreciate your help!!

Comment: Could you send me the reference link or screenshot of that `CC image next to the form`

Comment: here you go
https://codepen.io/quinlo/pen/YONMEa

Comment: My goal is to use my own label design instead of the CC design.